# Tweaking table defined by exam class

Tags: exam

**Question:** Is it possible to remove the 0 point values in the `gradetable` using the [`exam`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam?lang=en) document class to produce a potentially useful table for exercise sheets and the like?

Here's my idea:

```
\documentclass[10pt,addpoints]{exam}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question Is it true that \(x^n + y^n = z^n\) 
if \(x,y,z\) and \(n\) are positive integers? Explain.

\question Prove that the real part of all non-trivial zeros of the function
\(\zeta(z)\) is \(\frac{1}{2}\) \ldots

\question Another question.
\end{questions}

\gradetablestretch{2}
\cvqword{Problem}
\cvpword{Understood}
\cvbpword{Confused}
\cvtword{Cumulative:}
\cvsword{\phantom{someemptytext}Note\phantom{someemptytext}}
\combinedgradetable[v]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea is that students could have a sort of cover sheet for homework exercises or similar assignments and they could easily keep tabs on the problems they felt like they understood or did not (so as to facilitate classroom discussion or asking questions). I also thought having a column just to jot down a note would be useful. It looks like I can exploit some of the options made available for `exam`, but the main issue is that I cannot make a `gradetable` without using the `addpoints` feature.

I tried looking at the package documentation and even `exam.cls` as to how I might go about a dirty solution, but alas I cannot figure out anything effectively.

Ultimately, I would like to have blank spaces where the 0s currently are and remove the bottom row altogether (I tried `cumulative` instead of `total` to dream up something possibly of use, but it's an infinite stretch).

I thought about trying to somehow duplicate the style of the `Note` column (which usually lists the `score` later to be filled in by the instructor), but I did not see how to possibly do this by looking at the class file or package documentation.