# Generating table rows where the number of rows depends on a counter

Tags: tables, counters, exam

This question arises from [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/385019/43245) that was specific to the `exam` document class, but there should, I imagine, be wider applicability here as well as usefulness outside of using `exam`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,addpoints]{exam}

\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question Question one.

\question Question two.

\question Question three.
\end{questions}

\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{2.5}
{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2em}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Problem & Understood & Confused & \phantom{someemptytext}Note\phantom{someemptytext} \\
\hline
\rownumber & {} & {} & {}\\
\hline
\rownumber & {} & {} & {}\\
\hline
\rownumber & {} & {} & {}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\egroup\\

Total number of questions: \numquestions. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used help from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21243/automatic-table-row-numbers) for the row numbers, but it seems like there should be an easy workaround for what I am trying to accomplish here. The table is how I would like it to look except I want the number of rows generated to be dictated by `\numquestions` from the `exam` class. As can be seen from the code, all `\numquestions` rows (3 in this case) are of the type

```
\rownumber & {} & {} & {}\\
\hline
```

Is there a way I can use `\numquestions` to make a table generate `\numquestions` rows of the type above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last value of `question` is still known when the `questions` environment ends, until a new one starts.

You can build a table based on this.

```
\documentclass[10pt,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{xparse,tabularx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__farlow_grading_tl
\NewDocumentCommand{\gradingtable}{}
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__farlow_grading_tl
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \value{question} }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__farlow_grading_tl
     {
      ##1 \vphantom{$\bigg|$} & & & \\ \hline
     }
   }
  \par\noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}
   {
    | c |
    >{\hsize=0.5\hsize} X |
    >{\hsize=0.5\hsize} X |
    >{\hsize=2.0\hsize} X |
   }
  \hline
  Problem &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Understood} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Confused} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Note} \\ \hline
  \tl_use:N \l__farlow_grading_tl
  \multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{{\small Number~of~problems:~\thequestion}}
  \end{tabularx}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question Question one.

\question Question two.

\question Question three.

\end{questions}

\gradingtable

\end{document}
```

[image]

For placing the table above the questions (requires two runs to synchronize):

```
\documentclass[10pt,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{xparse,tabularx,refcount,etoolbox}

\newcounter{grading}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{questions}{%
  \stepcounter{grading}%
  \gradingtable
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{questions}{%
  \addtocounter{question}{-1}%
  \refstepcounter{question}%
  \label{grading\thegrading @label}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__farlow_grading_tl
\NewDocumentCommand{\gradingtable}{}
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__farlow_grading_tl
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \getrefnumber{grading\thegrading @label} }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__farlow_grading_tl
     {
      ##1 \vphantom{$\bigg|$} & & & \\ \hline
     }
   }
  \par\noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}
   {
    | c |
    >{\hsize=0.5\hsize} X |
    >{\hsize=0.5\hsize} X |
    >{\hsize=2.0\hsize} X |
   }
  \hline
  Problem &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Understood} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Confused} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Note} \\ \hline
  \tl_use:N \l__farlow_grading_tl
  \multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{{\small Number~of~problems:~\getrefnumber{grading\thegrading @label}}}
  \end{tabularx}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question Question one.

\question Question two.

\question Question three.

\end{questions}

\begin{questions}

\question Question one again.

\question Question two again.

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow The main part is to define a suitable preamble for the table; `tabularx` is used only for convenience; instead of changing `\arraystretch`, I insert a big strut. The body of the table is generated with `\int_step_inline:nnnn`, not that difficult. `;-)`

Comment: You are the LaTeX *deus ex machina* to be sure. I will keep on my journey though that someday maybe I'll be able to look at something like that and see it as "not that difficult." `:-)`

Comment: Is it at all possible with a minor change to have the modified grade table *before* the `questions` environment or does that ruin the structural integrity of your answer (I know you said you could build a table based on the value of `question` when the `questions` environment ends). I ask because that was originally my main intention (with using `numquestions` somewhere) but your answer is rather beyond me in terms of whether or not that would be a minor change or a complete restructuring.

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow I can think to a two-pass procedure. Stay tuned.

Comment: This is fantastic. Thanks for the awesome work and saving me many hours of frustration (I was even able to moderately understand your code and modify one or two things to get exact placement of the table how I wanted it!). `:-)`

Comment: Is it possible to modify your code while maintaining the integrity of your answer to preserve hyperlinking of questions in the `exam` document class when `hyperref` is loaded? I've posted a question about this [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/411667/43245), but thought I would ask you on this original thread.

Answer (score 1):

Constructing `table` rows within loops is 'difficult' due to grouping. `expl3` helps here with `\prg_replicate:nn` which replicates the same content according to the first argument, which is `\number\value{numquestions}`.

I additionally used the new `R` columntype that automatically counts the lines, but this can be shifted to the macro `\displaytherows` as well.

```
\documentclass[10pt,addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\themagicrownumbers}c}

\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\displaytherows}{%
  \prg_replicate:nn {\exam@numquestions}{ & {} & {} & {} \tabularnewline \hline}
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}


\begin{questions}
\question Question one.

\question Question two.

\question Question three.
\end{questions}

\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{2.5}
{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2em}
  \begin{tabular}{|R|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{Problem} & Understood & Confused & \phantom{someemptytext}Note\phantom{someemptytext} \tabularnewline
    \hline
    \displaytherows
  \end{tabular}
}
\egroup

Total number of questions: \numquestions. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get an `undefined control sequence` error when running your code above for `\displaytherows`. Does that mean something I am running is outdated? Oops maybe the issue is `\exam@numquestions`. Whatever it is, there's an `undefined control sequence` issue. Trying to resolve.

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow: It works for me -- do you have copied my code as is, with the `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair as well?

Comment: Yes (complete copy and paste), and it's still throwing the error. I'm using MiKTeX if that's relevant and pdfLaTeX to compile. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/JTnY8Tk.png) is the error message.

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow: Sigh (MikTeX), well I use `TeXLive 2017`, with daily updates on Linux, but the last `expl3` update should have entered `MikTeX` already...

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow: what does `\meaning\numquestions` provide for you, e.g. right after `\begin{document}`?

Comment: Nothing is provided. There's no error. It's only on the line with `\displaytherows`. I can't see any effect that `\meaning\numquestions` has.

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow: Strange, but I changed my answer regarding that line

Comment: Yes, it must be an issue with needing to update my system (can't thin of anything else that could explain it). Thank you for your help though.