# Preserving hyperlinked questions with a modified exam gradetable

Tags: tables, macros, hyperref, labels, exam

A few months ago egreg gave a [wonderful answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/385113/43245) to a question I had about a modified gradetable using the `exam` document class. More recently, after loading the `hyperref` package, I realized the hyperlinking to a question's location from the modified table was not preserved.

Perhaps it's easy for a more experienced user to tell why this is the case, but egreg's code is quite beyond me. I'm wondering whether or not there's a way to modify the following code to preserve hyperlinking of questions:

```
\documentclass[10pt,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{xparse,tabularx,refcount,etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{grading}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{questions}{%
  \stepcounter{grading}%
  \gradingtable
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{questions}{%
  \addtocounter{question}{-1}%
  \refstepcounter{question}%
  \label{grading\thegrading @label}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__farlow_grading_tl
\NewDocumentCommand{\gradingtable}{}
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__farlow_grading_tl
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \getrefnumber{grading\thegrading @label} }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__farlow_grading_tl
     {
      ##1 \vphantom{$\bigg|$} & & & \\ \hline
     }
   }
  \par\noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}
   {
    | c |
    >{\hsize=0.5\hsize} X |
    >{\hsize=0.5\hsize} X |
    >{\hsize=2.0\hsize} X |
   }
  \hline
  Problem &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Understood} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Confused} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Note} \\ \hline
  \tl_use:N \l__farlow_grading_tl
  \end{tabularx}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\fullwidth{\lipsum[1-2]}

\question First question.

\question Second question.

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following:

[image]

In the code above, I only notably modified egreg's [original code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/385113/43245) by loading the `hyperref` package as well as got rid of *two* `question` environments. With what I have in mind, I only need one `questions` environment, but it would be ideal if the question numbers in the table hyperlinked to the appropriate numbered question in the document.

Is there a relatively easy way to modify egreg's code to accomplish this or is it largely a lost cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is tell TeX that when it's making the table, instead of dropping numbers it should drop hyper links. So change this line:

```
  ##1 \vphantom{$\bigg|$} & & & \\ \hline
```

to

```
\ref{question@##1} \vphantom{$\bigg|$} & & & \\ \hline
```

That is the line which makes the blank table at the beggining of each environment. It loops through some labels that were set up and dumps them in the table. From doing some research in the package (namely seeing the definition of `\process@question` from the expansion of `\question`), there is a label set at each question called `question@*number*`. We replaced the numbers that egreg put in with these labels, and the hyperlinks are there.